# Installing Windows from External HDD

Tags: windows, installation, external-hard-drive, iso-image

I have external hard drive with some data (movies, music, apps, etc.) and I am wondering whether I can use it as bootable HDD to install windows from it, I have installer on my second PC and I am not sure if the fact I have other data on this external HDD may cause any problem when installing Windows using it?
I am trying to install one of the following: Windows 7 Ultimate Windows XP Professional

preferably the solution(s) should apply to both, because not yet decided which one I will use.

Thanks in advance for any help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have partition in your external HDD means possible to make as boot-able without affect data.

But if it is single partition, upto i know you can't do it.

Try to make it as 2 or more partition with some disk management tools then make iso to usb with some installers. After that you can. It'll be applicable both windows 7 and xp.

Comment: Thanks Kumar, another question regarding it as I am not sure if disk management tools work the same way with external and internal HDDs? Does it matter? I am just afraid of losing my data after that.

Comment: @pzet I cant conform about windows disk management tools. But i can tell Partition wizard 5 and Easeus Partition Manager are better than that.